# IE document element has symbols, how to reference?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

Probably a simple one for you gurus, I'm trying to use vbscript to screen scrape however the document element I am trying to put data into in order to run the form on this site has symbols in it and VBscripting is erroring on identifier...

```
With IE.Document.aspnetForm
    .l00$_SUMMARY$txtIP.value = server_ip
    .submit
End With
```

Here is the view source of this element from the web page

```
<input name="ctl00$_SUMMARY$txtIP" type="text" id="ctl00_SUMMARY_txtIP" style="width:100px;" />
```

Thanks all,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo .HTA shows three (of the twentynine) ways to my baby's door:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <hta:application id="demo square brackets" scroll="No"></hta>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script language = "VBScript"
          type     = "text/vbscript"
  >
  Sub onLoad()
    MsgBox "A " & document.all.[ctl00$_SUMMARY$txtIP].value
    MsgBox "B " & document.getElementById("ctl00$_SUMMARY$txtIP").value
    MsgBox "C " & document.getElementById("ctl00_SUMMARY_txtIP").value
  End Sub
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="onLoad">
  <input name="ctl00$_SUMMARY$txtIP" type="text" id="ctl00_SUMMARY_txtIP" value="my baby's door" />
 </body>
</html>
```

[] can be used generally in VBScript to feed identifiers with funny letters or spaces to the engine; getElementById takes name and id attributes into account.